White labeling Excel PowerApps add-in
My client asked me to white label excel  https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380330?src=office&corrid=c97890ab-6f1c-fcae-e736-14985f9b7323&omexanonuid=&referralurl=&ClientSessionId=9779c341-05e0-428a-a5dd-06494dacd4ee add-in. As far as I understand it's a web based add-in working inside of an iframe, however it's installable into desktop excel (office 2016) as well. The problem is I don't understand how to download it, pack into a standalone installer or put on my web server and install to excel 2016.
At first I tried to use procmon and wireshark, but didn't get much information except for interesting iexplore cache files containing icons of logos, name, etc. Then I managed to open the add-in in web version of Excel and it allowed to open web tools network tab and find out URLs the iframe uses. I tried to open the main html in a new tab, however it didn't show any UI elements. Now I need to copy, modify, deploy and somehow install the add-in into excel. I feel like the task is unusual and maybe not feasible at all. Please advice how to proceed with this task, thanks

What you're client is asking is probably license violation or plain illegal, as this Addin is not Open Source. Thus even if you somehow manage to integrate it, you still need to do it without tampering the original labelling.

When I have similar issues the CurlWget plugin has helped me.
Initiate the download once (via manual steps) and then use CurlWget to get a link. In my experience running
wget LONG_CurlWget_Link

Initiates a headless download. Handy for automation/scripting.

The excel addin is a web based software, if your customer owned the required addin, you should have access to the source code, and can learn how to modify it in Microsoft addin development documentation
